# Prolog list exercise

Tags: prolog

Here is my exercise: define a predicate in prolog which, applied to a list L of integers, gives as a result the list of the successors of the even elements present in L.

The code i wrote work only if one element is even , can someone help me figure out where I'm wrong?

```
even(X):- 0 is mod(X,2).
odd(X):- 1 is mod(X,2).

list_even([],[]).    
list_even([T|C],K):- even(T), E is T+1, list_even(C,K1), append(K1,E,X), K is X.
list_even([T|C],K):- odd(T),list_even(C,K).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some flaws in your code are:

- `append(K1, E, X)`: This goal should append two lists to generate a third list; however, `E` is just an element, not a list. So you need to write `append(K1, [E], X)`.
- `K is X`: This goal evaluates the arithmetic expression represented by the variable `X` and unifies its value with variable `K`; however, `X` is a list, not an arithmetic expression. So you need to remove it.

So the correct code would be as follows:

```
list_even([], []).
list_even([T|C], K):- even(T), E is T+1, list_even(C, K1), append(K1, [E], K).
list_even([T|C], K):- odd(T), list_even(C, K).
```

Example:

```
?- list_even([1, 20, 3, 40, 5, 7, 8], Successors).
Successors = [9, 41, 21] ;
false.
```

Note that in the obtained answer, the successors appear in reverse order (the first even element in the input list is `20`, but its successor `21` is the last element in the output list).

So a better code is as follows:

```
even_number_successors([], []).
even_number_successors([X|Xs], Successors) :-
   (   X mod 2 =:= 0
   ->  Y is X + 1,
       Successors = [Y|Ys]
   ;   Successors = Ys ),
   even_number_successors(Xs, Ys).
```

Example:

```
?- even_number_successors([1, 20, 3, 40, 5, 7, 8], Successors).
Successors = [21, 41, 9].
```

Answer (score 0):

From your problem statement,

> define a predicate in prolog which, applied to a list `L` of integers, gives as a result the list of the successors of the even elements present in `L`.

- On the face of things, you don't need `odd/1`: that which is not even is odd.
- Why use `append/3`? You're just iterating/filtering a list and constructing a new one, right? Instead, you can construct the list in order by leaving the list incomplete, with an unbound tail. As we recurse down, we build out the tail of the list, either by  unifying it with a new list, or at the end, unifying it with the empty list, the atom `[]`).

I would do something like this:

```
list_even( []     , []     ) .  % empty list? All done.
list_even( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] ) :- % non-empty?
  even(X),                      % - is X even? if so...
  !,                            % - eliminate the choice point
  Y is X+1,                     % - get the successor of X
  list_even(Xs,Ys)              % - recurse down
  .                             %
list_even( [_|Xs] ,    Ys  ) :- % Otherwise, the head of the list is odd: discard the head, and...
  list_even(Xs,Ys)              % - recurse down
  .                             % Easy!

even(X) :- 0 =:= X .
```